# Numix theme segmentation fault (Pdfchain)

Tags: gnome, numix

I have a strange bug under Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. After I apply Numix theme in the apperance (with numix circle icon theme but its not depend for the problem), the pdfchain application won't start. If I change back to Adwaita theme, the pdfchain will start normally. With terminal:

```
(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2903:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2908:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2913:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2918:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2923:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2928:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2933:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

(pdfchain:5507): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2938:18: '-gtk-icon-shadow' is not a valid property name

PDF Chain 0.4.4 - A graphical user interface for the PDF Toolkit

Segmentation fault
```

So, strange, if I start the app with Adwaita, and switch back to Numix, its working, but if I quit and try to start again, it won't start.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: It is a [known bug logged on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdfchain/+bug/1668564). Possibly related to [this seg fault issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/843237/38585)?