# Pdfchain doesn't start, crashed with segfault

Tags: 16.04

Pdfchain doesn't start. When trying to start from terminal I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Still getting the `Segmantation fault` message with 17.10, installed either from pdfchain-team ppa, or from Software channel. :( Worked so well in 16.04 LTS. Fortunately, `pdftk` works [from command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/282455/38585).

Comment: And it is a confirmed bug [reported on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdfchain/+bug/1685778). Hopefully this means there will be a fix soonish.

Answer (score 0):

I will first try purge pdfchain:

```
sudo apt-get purge pdfchain
```

And check. If this doesnt work try to reinstall it with and purge config too:

```
sudo apt-get remove pdfchain
sudo apt-get purge pdfchain
```

Then install it :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pdfchain-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pdfchain
```

Tell me if it works. If not you may try to debug the pdgchain with gdb for example.

Comment: You don't need to remove and purge. Just purge will remove the software and delete the configuration files.

Comment: I would leave the ppa repository out. `pdfchain` is in Ubuntu 16.04, and likely to be more stable than a release from PPA.

Comment: It didn't work.. Must be some hidden options I can't delete when unisntalling.

Comment: Me neither on Ubuntu 16.10 with PDF Chain 0.4.4. Using `ppa:pdfchain-team/ppa` did not change the result.